# ¿Utilizar los botones de datatables?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

Quiero agregar el boton para exportar a Excel con DataTables, pero me genera el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function` según investigue el error se debe a cargar primero el script de datatables antes del script de jquery, pero aún luego de cambiar el orden sigue el mismo error.

el código de mi vista es el siguiente:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabla_operaciones').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtipo',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength: 50,
    ajax:{
        url: 'listado_operaciones',
        dataSrc: 'data',
    },
    buttons: [
            'excel'
                                  ],
    columns: [
        { data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        { data: 'name', name:  'users.name'},
        { data: 'noboleta', name: 'noboleta' },
        { data: 'tipo', name: 'tipos.tipo'},
        { data: 'nombre', name: 'bancos.nombre'},
        { data: 'monto', name: 'monto'},
        { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
        { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
        { data: 'estado', name: 'estados.estado'},
        { data: 'autorizacion', name: 'autorizacion'},
            ]
});
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: eso se debe a dos cosa, una que no existe la librería, la otra es que el campos  <table id="tabla_operaciones"> no lo encuentras o lo llama antes de recargar la pagina por lo cual se deber colocar el código js al final de la estructura de la pagina

Comment: el problema aparace al intentar agregar el boton de exportar a excel, si elimino la parte de $(document).ready(function() entonces sí me carga todos los datos a la vista, y los script estan al final